# Deserialization error using OptionalField

Tags: c#, .net, mono

After I add a new optional field to a class, previously serialized instances of this class are no longer deserializable.

Suppose I have saved some instances of MyClass using the BinaryFormatter:

```
[Serializable]
public class MyClass
{
    public MyType A;
}
```

After, a second revision of MyClass:

```
[Serializable]
public class MyClass
{
    public MyType A;

    [OptionalField(VersionAdded = 2)]
    public MyType NewField;
}
```

Now older objects are no longer deserializable. The stack trace that I obtain when trying to deserialize them is the following (the profile is .NET 4.0):

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.    
Parameter name: type    
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(Type type)    
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryConverter.GetParserBinaryTypeInfo(Type type, Object& typeInformation)    
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectMap..ctor(String objectName, Type objectType, String[] memberNames, ObjectReader objectReader, Int32 objectId, BinaryAssemblyInfo assemblyInfo)    
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.ReadObjectWithMap(BinaryObjectWithMap record)    
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.Run()    
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)    
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)    
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)    
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck)
```

I cannot find this stack trace on the internet or similar stack traces. Note that the same files are readable running the software with Mono ;-) . Because of this I suppose that the problem could be related to a .NET bug.

Comment: How exactly are you deserializing it? Can you add that code?

Comment: VersionAdded property is marked as reserved on .NET 4, try to run your code without it.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose I have the following class types.

```
[Serializable]
public class MyClass
{
    public MyType A;
}

[Serializable]
public class MyType
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Let's serialize an instance of MyClass to a file.

```
using (var stream = new FileStream(@"c:\temp\test.dat", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
{
    var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    formatter.Serialize(stream, new MyClass { A = new MyType { Name = "Christophe" } });
}
```

Now we deserialize it back into an instance of MyClass.

```
using (var stream = new FileStream(@"c:\temp\test.dat", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    var myInstance = (MyClass) formatter.Deserialize(stream);
}
```

No problem. Everything works fine. Let's add a new field to the MyClass type. I would suggest you use properties instead.

```
[Serializable]
public class MyClass
{
    public MyType A;

    [OptionalField]
    public MyType B;
}
```

Deserialization still works fine. In my case the missing data for B is ignored and it is set to null.

Comment: Thanks, the situation you describe is exactly my case, but in my case I have an error. MyClass is a semplification, my real class have a lot of fields and an new optional field. I think that the problem is not related to the use of properties (and cannot be marked with the attribute OptionalField.


 Do you know where to post microsoft bugs?

Comment: I doubt it's a bug. Could you post how you deserialize and what exactly is MyType?

Comment: I have this problem too!  .NET serialization is BUGGY!  This isn't the first (nor the second) time I've had incomprehensible problems with serialization.  Things that should work, don't.  [Nonserialized] ALSO doesn't work.

Comment: SOLVED IT; an exception was being thrown in my RunAfterDeserialization method, making it appear that deserialization had failed.  Doh!